# How to publish magazines (in PDF format) to Apple Newsstand?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

We're interested in publishing our magazines to Apple's Newsstand and we're wondering how we would go about doing this?

I've read you need a developer kit (which we don't have), is there a way to just publish the magazines without this?

Comment: There might also be some news related to this at tomorrow's event: http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2012/01/apple-to-announce-tools-platform-to-digitally-destroy-textbook-publishing.ars

Comment: Now that a year of Newsstand development has occurred, it's now free to develop and $100 for a year of time selling on the store to be any sort of iOS developer. See [this newer question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87005/what-applications-do-i-need-to-make-a-newsstand-app) on what's needed today to publish in 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not have a dev kit you can use other companies who build, release and manage subscriptions.

One such comapny is [Woodwing](http://www.woodwing.com/en/tablet-publishing-overview)

However these options are generally very expensive. You are better off (if you can create and develop the product yourself) purchasing the SDK license ($99 per year) or failing that you can use [Adobe software](http://www.adobe.com/products/digital-publishing-suite-family/buying-guide-pricing.html) to publish the Newsstand Magazine but that costs about $500

There is more information on [Newsstand here](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/newsstand/)

Comment: Thanks. We don't have any of the expertise in house to build apps. I didn't realise you had to build an app to publish things to the news stand. I can't believe it's so complicated to publish a PDF!

Comment: It is not always just a PDF, a lot of newsstand apps have digital media content, such as sound and video

Comment: Ok, is there not some kind of watered down service to publish magazines without the need to create an app?

Comment: added link to adobe digital software in answer

Answer (score 2):

Among the various solutions you can choose from, there's iTablo that does exactly what you're looking for: [iTablo site](http://www.itablo.com)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a watered down solution, but rather one that takes a different approach to the problem. You can use [Brainiac Publishing](http://www.brainiacpub.com) to port your magazines to iOS (disclosure - I'm a founder).

The service has minimal upfront costs (starts at $10 a page) with all other fees tied to downloads and sales — that's 30% of sales to Apple, 10% to Brainiac, and a download fee of $.20 tied to Adobe DPS. The creation of the Newsstand app, design template, etc. are all done without cost to the publisher. So, publishers clear 40% on $.99 publications and 50% on $1.99 publications. (If you're free, you pay $.30 per download.)

The only caveat is that distribution (or projected distribution) has to be reasonably high since it's a back end revenue model — no back end, no revenue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at [www.lazypub.com](http://www.lazypub.com) (disclaimer: I am a founder).
It is very easy to publish PDFs in your own branded newsstand app and even enhance those PDF files with interactive elements (videos, mp3 files, image galleries, URLs) without any programming skills. LazyPub allows you to create Newsstand applications with all newsstand-related features (subscriptions, in app purchases etc)

Comment: Thank you for the disclosure. Would you clarify if your solution allows selling on Apple's Newsstand app as specified in the question. My understanding of he web site is you are hosting a parallel service that bypasses Apple's store and billing. If so, we might want to find that question (or you can ask it yourself) - _What are alternative stores for iOS users to consume content in a similar manner to Newsstand?_