# What applications do i need to make a Newsstand app?

Tags: ios, ibooks-author, newsstand

I am wondering how to make a newsstand app. What are the applications i need? I am currently in the process of enrolling in the Apple iOS program, so i will have access to the Newsstand Kit and Framework. But how should i make my content, i have read you can use iBooks Author, or InDesign and export them as PDF's, but in PDF's you loose video, and other widgets. Please help me.

Comment: This is a fine question for here, but do read the [faq]. We consider topics that are covered by an NDA or are beta software or are code level developer questions to be off-topic. This broad question is fine since even Apple lists many resources publicly for people to download the tools and learn about Newsstand, but at some point, you will have to take your technical questions to either http://stackoverflow.com or https://developer.apple.com/devforums/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newstand content is simply an iOS Application that makes use of the [Newsstandkit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/NewsstandKit_Framework/_index.html), so you might start with [Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/app/xcode/id497799835) and a one year membership to the [iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).

When you enroll in the latter, you will learn what things can be discussed and asked about publicly and which parts of the program are covered by an Non-Disclosure Agreement (NDA).

You don't need the paid membership to download Xcode and start learning and crafting your first Newsstand app, but you do get access to many training videos, a [discussion area where you can speak to other developers and Apple](https://developer.apple.com/devforums/) on NDA topics. The ability to sign and install apps you develop on some test devices to work on development before they are ready for sale on the App Store is also critical for proper QA.

There are also many other paid options to developer Newsstand apps, but I would start with free and training like the dedicated page for developers to learn Newstand:

- https://developer.apple.com/newsstand/